# How to get a substring out of a document that is being iterated through but constantly changing

Tags: java, string, list, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to iterate through a document that I have read into a list and need to get a specific string of info that is in the middle of each line and print that string of info into a line, the problem is the string changes with each line like reading a bunch of ID's that are surrounded by other amounts of info

I tried converting the list into a string and using doc.substring(doc.lastIndexOf("S") but this only get the last ID and prints this same ID for each line of text instead of pairing the specific ID with the rest of its info.

```
public static void doStuff(List<String> text) {
        char type = 'x';
        int bed = 0;
        double rentDue = 0;
        String ID;
        String doc = text.toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
            if (text.get(i).charAt(0) == 'S') {
                ID = doc.substring(doc.lastIndexOf("S"));
                type = text.get(i).charAt(0);
                bed = Character.getNumericValue(text.get(i).charAt(text.size() + 4));
                rentDue = Payment.processPayment(type, bed);
                System.out.print(type);
                System.out.print("    ");
                System.out.print(bed);
                System.out.print("    ");
                System.out.print(rentDue);
                System.out.print("    ");
                System.out.print(ID);
            } else {
                ID = doc.substring(doc.lastIndexOf("A"));
                type = text.get(i).charAt(0);
                bed = Character.getNumericValue(text.get(i).charAt(text.size() + 4));
                rentDue = Payment.processPayment(type, bed);
                System.out.print(type);
                System.out.print("    ");
                System.out.print(bed);
                System.out.print("    ");
                System.out.print(rentDue);
                System.out.print("    ");
                System.out.print(ID);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
Expected: 
S    3    1352.0 SABQ138
A    2    864.0 AABQ205
S    1    936.0 SABQ127
A    2    864.0 AABQ313
S    2    1144.0 SABQ126
A    2    864.0 AABQ302
Actual:
S    3    1352.0    SABQ126 2, A AABQ302 2]
A    2    864.0    ABQ302 2]
S    1    936.0    SABQ126 2, A AABQ302 2]
A    2    864.0    ABQ302 2]
S    2    1144.0    SABQ126 2, A AABQ302 2]
A    2    864.0    ABQ302 2]
```

Comment: I've been printing the String "doc" and I know its just going to print the whole document, I was trying to isolate the "ID" and was just get the last ID of the whole document that started with the letter specified, it obviously didn't work and I can't really think of anything else

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the ID from the whole document if it is part of the current line?

Comment: We have to extract the ID from the original document that was read in and the pair it with new info (the rent) that is solved for elsewhere in the class, it has to be in a specific format that uses polymorphic objects and simply taking the line and printing it again wouldn't meet the criteria

Comment: I was not thinking about "taking the line and printing it again", I was thinking about `ID = text.get(i).substring(text.get(i).lastIndexOf("S"));`

Comment: I now completely get what you mean but I'm honestly so confused as to how to go about getting the ID out of the specific line that I'm on

Comment: OK after tons of toying around I was able to finally get it, its not pretty but it works and I was able to set the ID to a variable that is in fact correct you were actually very helpful thank you!